# go use connection pool connect mysql occured socket leak

Tags: mysql, go, gorp

#### go verison 1.9.2

#### go-sql-driver/mysql git commit hash cd4cb90

#### mysql server version: 5.6.15-log MySQL Community Server

#### os version:CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

#### db open config

max_idle_conns = 5

max_open_conns = 30

max_life_time=600

timeout=600

#### mysql config

```
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 60       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| interactive_timeout         | 600      |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| log_output                  | FILE     |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 600      |
+-----------------------------+----------+
```

#### lsof output

srv_promo 12672 root   10u  sock      0,6      0t0 63382668 can't identify protocol

srv_promo 12672 root   11u  sock      0,6      0t0 63366850 can't identify protocol

srv_promo 12672 root   12u  sock      0,6      0t0 63366688 can't identify protocol

srv_promo 12672 root   13u  sock      0,6      0t0 63366690 can't identify protocol

[mysql config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFvxf.png)

[lsof output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw6d4.png)

#### below is code:

package dbtest

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/golang/glog"
    "gopkg.in/gorp.v2"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type DatabaseConfig struct {
    DBName               string `toml:"dbname"`
    Host                 string `toml:"host"`
    Port                 int    `toml:"port"`
    User                 string `toml:"user"`
    Password             string `toml:"password"`
    Sslmode              string `toml:"sslmode"`
    ShowLog              bool
    DataSaveDir          string
    DataFileSaveLoopSize int
    MaxIdleConns         int `toml:"max_idle_conns"`
    MaxOpenConns         int `toml:"max_open_conns"`
    MaxLifeTime          int `toml:"max_life_time"`
    Timeout              int `toml:"timeout"`
    RTimeout             int `toml:"rtimeout"`
    WTimeout             int `toml:"wtimeout"`
}

func (c DatabaseConfig) MySQLSource() string {
    params := make(map[string]string, 0)
    params["charset"] = "utf8mb4"
    cfg := mysql.Config{}
    cfg.User = c.User
    cfg.Passwd = c.Password
    cfg.DBName = c.DBName
    cfg.ParseTime = true
    cfg.Collation = "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
    cfg.Params = params
    cfg.Loc, _ = time.LoadLocation("Asia/Chongqing")
    cfg.Timeout = time.Duration(c.Timeout) * time.Second
    cfg.MultiStatements = true
    cfg.ReadTimeout = time.Duration(c.RTimeout) * time.Second
    cfg.WriteTimeout = time.Duration(c.WTimeout) * time.Second
    return cfg.FormatDSN()
}

var (
    dbmap     *gorp.DbMap
    Dbm       *gorp.DbMap
    config    DatabaseConfig
    opened    bool
    openMutex sync.RWMutex
    DB        *sql.DB
)

//Open open the database for passport with config
func Open(cfg DatabaseConfig) {
    if !opened {
        config = cfg
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", config.MySQLSource())
        glog.Infof("open err %v ", err)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("sql.Open failed: %v", err))
        }
        if config.MaxLifeTime > 0 {
            db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Duration(config.MaxLifeTime) * time.Second)
        }
        db.SetMaxIdleConns(config.MaxIdleConns)
        db.SetMaxOpenConns(config.MaxOpenConns)
        db.Ping()
        DB = db
        // construct a gorp DbMap
        dbmap = &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "utf8mb4"}}
        Dbm = dbmap

        err = dbmap.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
        if err != nil {
            panic("create table failed " + err.Error())
        }
        openMutex.Lock()
        opened = true
        openMutex.Unlock()
        if config.ShowLog {
            dbmap.TraceOn("[gorp]", log.New(os.Stdout, schemaName+" ", log.Lmicroseconds))
        }
    }
}

//Close close the database for passport
func Close() {
    if dbmap != nil && opened {
        glog.Infof("close database %s for %s", config.DBName, schemaName)
        dbmap.Db.Close()
        openMutex.Lock()
        opened = false
        openMutex.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but too much for a comment.)

Two things:

1. Please try to come up with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)—first for yourself and second (if that alone won't help you solve your problem)—for us.

   What I mean, is that there's too much going on in your example: you're using `gorp` which is not a part of the Go standard library, and this package—which supposedly wraps `database/sql` machinery—*can do absolutely anything* when working with the database.

   That's not how such problems are approached.
   Instead, you should start from the ground up and first use
   plain `database/sql` layer and see whether it works.
   If it does, the problem is with that `gorp` thing.

   Another, however minor, detail is that you should not use
   3rd-party packages to do trivial stuff in your MCVEs;
   here, I'm talking about logging: in a stripped down example,
   the standard `fmt.Print*` functions would be just OK, or,
   if you feel like it's impossible to go full-on-Enterprise-y,
   the standard `log` package would fill the bill.
2. The SQL database layer in Go is explicitly designed to
   have the semantics which are quite unlike the SQL database layers
   implemented by other popular languages / frameworks.

   The Go's is different in that it was designed to handle *massive*
   workloads typically generated on the server software.
   Among other things, it means that

   - Database connections are pooled by default.
   - They are reused as needed, and when you execute a query or
     a statement which is not in a transaction, you don't know whether
     this will create a new connection or reuse an existing one,
     and if yes, then which one exactly.
   - New connections do not actually *connect* unless something
     is executed on them (or their `Ping()` method is called).

Comment: I think is the mysql server side closed the timeout connections ,and go side not check the connection is whether alive , so the connection is not closed until to socket leak.